# How to install PM2 on Node js 8?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have tried to install PM2 on my node js project that running on node JS 8. How to install PM2 on Node js 8 ?

Error message:

```
npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ikt@git+http://ikt.pm2.io/ikt.git#master (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/ikt):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error while executing:
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t http://ikt.pm2.io/ikt.git
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fatal: unable to access 'http://ikt.pm2.io/ikt.git/': Could not resolve host: ikt.pm2.io
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: exited with error code: 128
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@0.3.8 (node_modules/pm2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@0.3.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: What is your issue? It looks like warning message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For installing PM2 please use:

```
npm install -g pm2
```